# how to start lots of separated threads and sending string to them

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i m developing kinda downloader that every time a button has been pushed a class must start and take a string code from a URL and send codes to another class. i used a AsyncTask to getting strings from URL . but the problem is that every time i push buttons quickly , i have to wait till AsyncTask get the strings from URLs one by one. i wanna use runnable implemented class that allow me to start getting string from URLs in different threads and quickly but i do not know how?consider this that i have to send URLs to new threads and i do not want one of threads download another thread URL by mistake or in low speed of Internet.pleas help me
if you know another way to get html codes from different URLs without waiting please tell me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at official doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

It seems, in your case, you have to use standard [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) instead of AsyncTask.